# If $|X_{n}| \leq Y$ almost surely, show that $\sup_{n}|X_{n}|\leq Y$ almost surely as well.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $|X_{n}|\leq Y$ a.s., each $n$, $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. Show that $\sup_{n}|X_{n}|\leq Y$ a.s. also.

This seems pretty intuitive to me, since if $|X_{n}|\leq Y$ a.s., it is bounded above by $Y$, and the sup is the least of these upper bounds. But, somehow I feel like there is more to it than that (especially since this is a starred exercise in my textbook, indicating that it is more challenging than the others?)

What exactly is the trick to showing this mathematically rigorously, thereby showing what the problem is actually asking me to show?

Comment: If you replaced "almost surely" with "surely", your analysis correct.

Comment: I detect a [study group](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/569490/7003) in the making.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $N_n $ be the set for which $x_n \not \le Y$. Then $\mu N_n = 0$. Let $N = \cup_n N_n$, then we have $\mu N = 0$.

Then we have $X_n(\omega) \le Y(\omega) $ for all $\omega \in N^c$, hence $\sup_n X_n(\omega) \le Y(\omega) $ for all $\omega \in N^c$.

Comment: I guess what I'm not understanding is how you are sure that the sup is necessarily between X and Y. Is it because it's the least upper bound?

Comment: When $\omega \notin N$, you have $X_n(\omega) \le Y(\omega)$ for all $n$, hence $Y(\omega)$ is an upper bound for $X_n(\omega)$. It follows that $\sup_n X_n(\omega) \le Y(\omega)$.

Answer (score 8):

Watch the phrase "almost surely".  Here is a written-out statement of the problem:

> Suppose that for each $n$, there exists an event $A_n$ with $P(A_n) = 1$ such that for every $\omega \in A_n$, we have $|X_n(\omega)| \le Y(\omega)$.  Show that there exists an event $A$ with $P(A) = 1$ such that for every $\omega \in A$, we have $\sup_n |X_n(\omega)| \le Y(\omega)$.

Comment: (+1) Because it seems to me that for students first encountering the subject, what the standard shorthand notation hides is often as much (or more of) an impediment to learning the material than any difficulty with the concepts themselves.